# Continuous function and integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ with $\int^{b}_{a} f = 0$ and $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ then $f(x)=0$ $\forall x\in[a,b]$.

Proof: Suppose there exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $\frac{f(c)}{2}>0$. By continuity, for $\epsilon =\frac{f(c)}{2}$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $x\in [a,b] \cap (c-\delta, c+\delta)$  then $f(x)>\frac{f(c)}{2}$.

So choose $\delta^1>0$ to be so that $(c-\delta^1,c+\delta^1)\subseteq [a,b]$ and $(c-\delta^1,c+\delta^1)$ $\subseteq$ $(c-\delta, c+\delta)$ then

$\int^{b}_{a}f \geq f(c)\delta^1>0$. So we have a contradiction.

The existence of $\delta^1$ is intuitively and geometrically clear. How do I formally prove its existence though?

Comment: Assuming $c$ is not one of the boundary points $a$ or $b$, then $a<c<b$ so we can always choose a $\delta^1>0$ such that $a<c-\delta^1<c<c+\delta^1<b$. We can choose this by for example letting $\delta^1 = \min\{c-a,b-c\}/2$.

Comment: @Aldoggen: Reread your comment. Obviously, $f(c)/2>0 \iff f(c)>0$.

Comment: There is no harm if $c=a$ or $c=b$ - we just consider the half-open interval $[a, a+\delta^1)$ or $(b-\delta^1,b]$ accordingly.

Comment: @TedShifrin Of course! My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is not identically zero, then there exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) >0$. Now, from the continuity of $f$, if $\epsilon >0$ is given, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that: $$|x-x_{0}|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_{0})|< \epsilon$$
Thus, take $\epsilon <f(x_{0})$ and we have:
$$\int_{x_{0}-\delta}^{x_{0}+\delta}f(x)dx \le \int_{x_{0}-\delta}^{x_{0}+\delta}(f(x_{0})-\epsilon)dx = (f(x_{0})-\epsilon)2\delta > 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there exists $c\in[a,b]$ with $f(c)>0$. If $c=a$ then choose $\delta>0$ such that $c\in[a,a+\delta)\subset[a,b]$. If $c=b$ then choose $\delta>0$ such that $c\in(b-\delta,b]\subset[a,b]$. If $a<x<b$ then choose $\delta>0$ such that $(\delta-c,\delta+c)\subset[a,b]$. In any case, choose $\delta$ so that $f(x)>0$ on the relevant interval. Now let $\delta'=\frac\delta2$ and consider the relevant *closed* interval ($[a,a+\delta']$, $[b-\delta',b]$, or $[c-\delta',c+\delta']$ as according to $c=a$, $c=b$, or $a<c<b$). Since $f$ is continuous, it attains a minimum value on a closed interval; call it $\varepsilon$. Let $I$ be the relevant interval. Then $f(x)\geqslant \varepsilon$ for all $x\in I$. It follows that
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\ \mathsf dx \geqslant \int_I f(x)\ \mathsf dx \geqslant \int_I\varepsilon\ \mathsf dx >0,
$$
as $I$ has strictly positive Lebesgue measure. This of course contradicts the assumption that $\int_a^b f(x)\ \mathsf dx = 0$.

Comment: You're wrong. By taking $\epsilon = f(c)/2$, saying that $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon = f(c)/2$ gives precisely what OP said. Then, indeed, on the closed interval in question we get $f(x)\ge f(c)/2$.

Comment: I suppose you are right. I will modify my answer and leave it as an alternate proof.